# How do I send image data from a url using express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want my the `/image` of my app to return a random image, how can I do that?

### app.js:

```js
const app = express();

app.get('/image', async (req, res) => {
  const url = 'https://example.com/images/test.jpg';
  res.send(/**/);  // How do I send the image binary data from the url?
});
```

---

### index.html

In HTML, this image actually shows the content of the image `https://example.com/images/test.jpg`

```html
<img src="https://my-app.com/image" />
```

Comment: You need `res.sendFile(...);` for that. And you need to pick a random *file*, not a url.

Comment: The thing is, all the images are from the internet, not serving on my server. Is it possible? @ChrisG

Comment: In that case you can try `res.redirect()`, not sure if it works for images though. If not, you'll have to download the image on the server, then send back the file. Or maybe pipe the stream somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have the same problem, and this is my solution for this using `request` package, so you have to `yarn add request` or `npm i request` first.
your code should be like this

```
const request = require('request');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/image', async (req, res) => {
  const url = 'https://example.com/images/test.jpg';

  request({
    url: url,
    encoding: null
  }, 
  (err, resp, buffer) => {
    if (!err && resp.statusCode === 200){
      res.set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
      res.send(resp.body);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

There is `res.sendFile` in [Express API](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)

```
app.get('/image', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(filepath);
});
```

Comment: I want to send a file from a url but not static file, so it doesn't work :(

Comment: in this case you have **two choice** , first one you can save it then send using `res.sendFile` and then if you dont need it anymore you can remove it from store, second one instad of passing file try send `URL` instead and then in **client side** catch the URL and display the information

Answer (score 2):

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("node:https");
const app = express();
const port = 3000

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Paris&units=metric&appid=65441206f989bc53319e2689fccdc638";

  https.get(url, function(response){

    response.on("data", function(data){
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(data)
      const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon
      const imageUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + "@2x.png"

      res.write("<img src=" + imageUrl + " ></img>")
      res.send();
    })
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save all such image links in json or any of your choice data file and get from them randomly and forward and pass them through variable in response. Like: `res.send(imgURL: 'https://example.com/images/test.jpg');` or you can pass url variable in init.